# Facade and Repository pattern: they should be Singleton?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, repository, crud, facade

I've to design some Repositories to handles CRUD operations.
I will put all of these repos in one Facade.

Should this Facade be a Singleton?

An example:

FacadeLibrary [Singleton?]

-
BookRepository | ClientRepository | RentalRepository

Or maybe the Repository should be Singleton?

Or neither?

Comment: Nothing should be singleton: http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid

Answer (score 1):

No!!!! Avoid to use singleton. Singleton is something like a global variable on your system. Normally you should use singleton in case if the system prevent you to create some resource more than one time. For example in Direct3D you cannot create Direct3D environment two times so there you could use a singleton but in any other case avoid to use it.

Comment: I really don't like the MVC design pattern because it is not really OO. And moreover it doesn't matter which framework use which pattern. I prefer to make my data to be related with the logic.

Comment: I'm with Alex on this. Back when applications were fat-clients and things were simpler, you could get away with class-based or singleton data access. Those days are gone. It's too easy to paint yourself into a corner with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is add a static property to the type itself to get to that type's repository. The method uses the IoC to resolve it:

```
public class Book
{
    public static IBookRepository Repository { get { return IoC.Resolve<IBookRepository>(); } }
    ...
}
```

Then I can make calls like

```
Book myBook = Book.Repository.Find(id);
```

I like this because it keeps Book-y-ness things together and allows me to swap in/out different implementations for the repository for testing by configuring IoC.

Comment: But it is not really object oriented you can just use namespaces in order to group your function. Actually a book is an object so you should represent the Book's state somehow.